# Unable to connect to teradata from Linux

Tags: php, odbc, teradata

I have installed teradata in Linux box and made odbc.ini file settings

but when I tried to connect to the Teradata I am getting below error

```
/opt/teradata/client/14.10/odbc_64/bin/tdxodbc: /usr/lib64/libodbc.so: no versio
n information available (required by /opt/teradata/client/14.10/odbc_64/bin/tdxo
dbc)

Enter Data Source Name: TD_ODBC

Enter UserID: XXXXXXXXX

Enter Password:


Connecting with SQLConnect(DSN=TD_ODBC,UID=****,PWD=*)...

adhoc: SQLError() couldn't find text, RC=100
```

ODBC connection closed.

can some body help me out why I am getting this error

Comment: Could you tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Teradata client has been installed in the path /opt/teradata/client/14.10/odbc_64

Comment: how can I reply you with my answer

Comment: Teradata client has been installed in the path /opt/teradata/client/14.10/odbc_64
and I included below content in odbc,ini file

[TD_ODBC]
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdata.so
DBCName=172.29.1.91
SessionMode=ANSI
UserName=
password=
MaxRespSize=1048576

and in odbc.inst file

[ODBC DRIVERS]
Teradata=Installed

[Teradata]
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdata.so
APILevel=CORE
ConnectFunctions=YYY
DriverODBCVer=3.51
SQLLevel=1

Comment: and I tried this command /opt/teradata/client/14.10/odbc_64/bin/tdxodbc in unix to check wether I am able to connect to teradata or not ?by entering the DSN name as TD_ODBC and username and paswword

Comment: Just edit your question.